# I have a 14 year old Kenmore french door refrigerator how long should it take to get back to tempature after repair?

Tags: freezer

My 14 year old Kenmore french foor refrigerator freezer combo was recently repaired for a loud fan noise and the freezer not keeping temp. It was about 62° when the repair was completed. 45 minutes later. It is 58°. I am not sure the repair fixed the problem. How long should it take to get temp?

Comment: 5 degrees an hour is not unreasonable if it's completely warm. They are made to maintain temps, not reduce them, and if they build enough cooling capacity to go faster it would cost more, run short-cycled, be worse the environment, and leave less room for food.

Comment: How long it takes depends on whether its full of a bunch of warm stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This gets awkward if you don't have another fridge to keep your food in.

Stock advice is to give it 24 hours to stabilize, but that does seem like terribly slow response. Which could mean "the repair didn't work" and it could mean "the reason for the repair being needed caused ice build-up in air passages that are still partially blocked." Which a *good* repair person might have noticed.

So what it may actually need (unless it sat for a long time powered off while waiting to be repaired) is a good long defrost (food out, power off, doors open, point a fan at the open doors) to clear out the air passages. Easy if you have a spare fridge, hard if not.

Answer (score 0):

It should blow cold air within 5 minutes and then maybe an hour or two to get the fridge stabilized.  Sometimes the freezer section takes multiple cycles to stabilize.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say.

It depends how much food is in the fridge and the internal temperature of the food.

If there is a lot of heavy food and it's all at 62 degrees internally, it could take a couple of days.

But say the food is at 40 degrees internally, and 55 at the surface.  Your air temperature measurements will show 62 pretty quickly after you open the door.  This will be faster scenario.

If the fridge is mostly empty it should reach set temp within 12 hours or so.